# Do I need "but" in the following sentence?

Tags: conjunctions

> She has an ideal life and family. There's only one problem: she wants
>   to run away from home. (But) after talking with her friend, she
>   postpones the idea and come back to her parents.

A native English speaker told me I don't need the *but*. But without the *but* the sentence sounds strange to me. It sounds as if the last part, *"...after talking with her friend..."*, it's unrelated to the previous sentences; it's just an event that follows after.

Maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: Being a non-native speaker, I would prefer to put 'But' for clearer meaning-in-context. Here, 'but' acts as a connector.

Comment: Replace with *However*? *However, without the **but**, the sentence sounds*

Comment: _She has an ideal life and family, but there's only one problem; she wants to run away from home.  After talking with her friend however, she postpones the idea and goes back to her parents._

Comment: @Mamta D You mean the sentence sounds better by replacing *but* with *however*? Interesting. Why?

Comment: @alexchenco Beginning a sentence with **But** is not recommended. Additionally, too many repeats of **but** so I suggested he begin the sentence with *However*.

Comment: @alexchenco, The third sentence opposes the second.  To enhance the opposition, a "but" can be inserted.  It's as if the second sentence doesn't end with a period, and the third sentence is a clause, after a comma, say.

Comment: Take a look at http://grammarist.com/grammar/conjunctions-to-start-sentences/ and http://www.getitwriteonline.com/archive/032601startsentandbut.htm .  There are other sources, see http://www.google.com/search?q=starting+a+sentence+with+a+conjunction

Comment: @MamtaD - Not starting a sentence with _but_? That sounds like grade-school advice. There's nothing wrong with starting a sentence with _but_ (plenty of accomplished and reputable writers have done so), as long as it's not overused. More on ELU [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/593/is-it-really-incorrect-to-start-a-sentence-with-and) and [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152284), and on the web [here](http://grammar.about.com/od/grammarfaq/f/butsentencefaq.htm) and [here](http://www.nwp.org/cs/public/print/resource/457).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with many of the comments which suggested the use of "however."  "However" shows the contrast you want to use.  While it is becoming more common to start sentences with the word "But," the strictest grammar lovers (including myself) do not embrace it.   You do have some other unbalanced tenses in your sentences, though.  If you are interested, I show you one way to correct them below...

> She had an ideal life and family. There was only one problem: she wanted to run away from home.  However, after talking with her friend, she postponed the idea and went back to her parents.

Comment: I guess I'm not among the "strictest grammar lovers." Neither were [London, Dickens, Melville, Rand, Sinclair, Bronte, Huxley, or Fitzgerald](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192294/what-great-writers-have-used-coordinating-conjunctions-at-the-start-of-sentences/192605#192605), apparently. ([This](http://www.writewithjean.com/usage-and-grammar/can-a-sentence-start-with-but/) is worth reading, too.) The issue here should not be whether _however_ should be used in place of _but_; rather, it should be about whether any conjunct is needed at all.

Comment: @KittyConsltant Thanks for the answer. I'm curious, why did you turn the passage to the past tense?

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use *though*, like this:

> She has an ideal life and family. There's only one problem: she wants to run away from home. After talking with her friend, though, she postpones the idea and comes back to her parents.

As a side note, *postpones* implies her restless feelings are only gone temporarily, and that she'll want to leave home again soon. If that's not what you want to convey, try using *drops* instead of *postpones*.

Comment: ♦ I'm curious, why do you prefer *though* instead of *but*? The original phrase: "But after learning about the curious death of her chihuahua, she postpones the idea..." is longer so that's why I chose *but* instead.

Comment: @alex - I'm not sure I can explain why I "prefer" it – or if I even do. You said that the "but" sounded strange to you, so I was offering another way to say the sentence without the _but_.